# Is there an option to fail early in tests when there is no activity?

Tags: java, vert.x, junit5

A simple integration test with *Vert.x* and *JUnit5* might look similar to the following code block.

```
@Test
@Timeout(value = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
void some_test(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
  // do nothing in this example.
}
```

This simple test will wait for 10 seconds and then fail due to the timeout. I want to know if there is an option to fail this tests early without waiting for the timeout. Since there is no activity, *Vert.x* could infer that the test will never be complete if it isn't already. With *no activity*, I mean that there are no running tasks nor timers. Only external operations could cause further actions but I imagine that many tests don't have such external triggers.

I would like to know if *Vert.x* provides the possibility to say *"There are no external triggers. Just stop when there is nothing left to do."*

Comment: I suppose, if only external operations would cause further activity there is no way for Vert.X or JUnit to infer that no external operations will happen within the next 10 seconds. If you do not have an external trigger, what is the test waiting for?

Comment: @SteffenJacobs, such test might have multiple verticle talking with each other. Therefore, the interoperability of multiple actors might be tested. Or just the message interface of one actor. In some cases, it might even happen that Vert.x is only used within the test to provide basic functionality like [periodic or delayd actions](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_executing_periodic_and_delayd_actions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vert.x is reactive which means that your implementation reacts on the events that other actors send over the event bus.

Normally, the only thing you can do is listen on the event bus. Your implementation cannot decide if the non-existence of external events is some kind of error. If the other actors have nothing to say, it can be a non-erroneous condition.

To decide if there are no external triggers and to fail the test early if nothing is left to do, can only be accomplished by gaining insights on the internal state of all other actors.

One could argue that this is not the task of a unit test, as other actors can be considered not being part of your unit.

**A suggestion for a solution**

All of your other actors (i.e. verticles) could at one point emit an event notifying your test-implementation, that they have finished their work and have nothing left to do.

Your test could count those **finished** events and act itself accordingly by calling `testContext.completeNow();`, as soon as it has received all **finished** events.

As far as I know, there is no option or tool in the vert.x-toolkit or junit to do this work for you. You would have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the answer correctly. Do you also want to say that such feature would not be possible or practical?

Comment: It is possible and if it's practical is up to you. I can image reasonable test cases. But I don't know of any built-in functions in vert.x or junit that would help you to solve the issue you have described in your question.

As far as I understand the reactive paradigm, the requirement "Just stop when there is nothing left to do." cannot be fulfilled by a framework-function but only by an individual implementation of the programmers themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will still wait a little bit before I accept the answer. Maybe someone has a definite answer whether the framework supports something relevant. Beside that, I still think *"Just stop when there is nothing left to do."* could be fulfilled by the framework. Note that having no external triggers basically means that all relevant threads are managed by Vert.x. Other actors are not external from the framework's point of view. But maybe it does not match the paradigm or is not worth the effort. Anyway, that is not really important for the question.